# Put a bit of HTML inside a <pre> tag?

Tags: html

How do I put a bit of HTML inside a  tag without escaping it? Or am I using an incorrect tag?

**P.S.** I cannot escape the HTML, it is produced by the server.

Comment: I think that's impossible by definition.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have no control over the emitted HTML, you can still encode it on the client side.

Here is how you would escape all markup inside `<pre>` tags using the jQuery library:

```
$(function() {
    var pre = $('pre');
    pre.html(htmlEncode(pre.html()));
});

function htmlEncode(value){ 
  return $('<div/>').text(value).html(); 
}
```

**Edit**: As requested, same code without using jQuery:

```
function encodePreElements() {
    var pre = document.getElementsByTagName('pre');
    for(var i = 0; i < pre.length; i++) {
        var encoded = htmlEncode(pre[i].innerHTML);
        pre[i].innerHTML = encoded;
    }
};

function htmlEncode(value) {
   var div = document.createElement('div');
   var text = document.createTextNode(value);
   div.appendChild(text);
   return div.innerHTML;
}
```

And run the `encodePreElements` after the DOM has been loaded:

```
<body onLoad='encodePreElements()'>
    <pre>Foo <b>bar</b></pre>
</body>
```

Comment: @Nick, added a non-jQuery solution.

Answer (score 15):

This:

```
    <pre>
      <&zwj;div>Hello<&zwj;/div>
    </pre>
```

Prints this:

```
<div>Hello</div>
```

Zero Width Joiner = `&zwj;`

Answer (score 3):

You **need** to escape the HTML, like so:

You can use HTML entities that are escaped and printed without compiling.

```
&#60; // will print <
&#62; // will print >
```

Using these two, you can print any HTML elements.

```
&#60;div&#62; // will print <div>
```

To solve your specific problem, you will need to parse the HTML string and convert the chevrons to these entities.

Answer (score 1):

You can also follow that way:

```
    <pre>
      <code>
        &lt;h1&gt;Hello World&lt;/h1&gt;
      </code>
    </pre>
```

With the above example you have this output:

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```