# Parsing and rewriting XHTML in one step?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to take this input:

```
<Person>
  <name>
    <first>John</first>
    <last>Galt</last>
  </name>
</Person>
```

And regex my way to this output:

```
<div>&lt;Person&gt;
  <div>&lt;name&gt;
    <div>&lt;firstt&gt;John&lt;/first&gt;</div>
    <div>&lt;lastt&gt;Galt&lt;/last&gt;</div>
  &lt;/name&gt;</div>
&lt;/Person&gt;</div>
```

I have a solution that *works:

```
var output = input.replace(/([<])\/([a-zA-Z][A-Z0-9]*)([^>]*)([>])/g, "&lt;$2$3&gt </div>");
    output = output.replace(/([<])([a-zA-Z][A-Z0-9]*)([^>]*)([>])/g, "<div>&lt;$2$3&gt;");
```

But I feel like its a little inefficient and was wondering if a regex savant could help me clean it up a little - ideally into one step?  My problem was that my regex couldn't handle nested elements (when I tried to do it all in one step).  Thanks!

**EDIT: Good catch racraman

Comment: Should ">John" be "&gt;John" ?   (Ditto for Galton)

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do what you're asking.  Found this that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060452/put-a-bit-of-html-inside-a-pre-tag

Answer (score 1):

To inject `<div>` and `</div>` You could've used empty-group matching:

```
input.replace(/(<(\/)[^>\/]*>)|(<[^>\/]*>)/g,"$1<$2div>$3");
```

This would've produced:

```
<div><Person>
  <div><name>
    <div><first>John</first></div>
    <div><last>Galt</last></div>
  </name></div>
</Person></div>
```

But You're also asking to replace `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively - known regexp engines don't support such group-content transformations within same step. E.g. You're limited to use either portions of matched groups or [quite primitive (uppercase/lowercase) transformation of those](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplacecase.html).

So I would've either simplified Yours:

```
var output = input.replace(/<\/([^>]*)>)/g, "&lt;$1&gt;</div>");
    output = output.replace(/<([^>\/]*)>/g, "<div>&lt;$1&gt;");
```

or would've used the empty-groups approach:

```
var ouptut = input.
replace(/<((\/)([^>\/]*)|([^>\/]*))>/g,"&lt;$2$3&gt;<$2div>&lt;$4&gt;").
replace(/&lt;&gt;/g,"");
```