# Vue.js <pre> tag in v-html

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm displaying content from ajax in a v-html element. The content contains a "pre" tag that i'd like to display as it should be.

Component :

```
<div v-html="content"></div>
```

Content example :

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<pre>
    <p>Hello</p>
</pre>
```

What I get :

> ## Title
>
> Hello

What i'd like to get :

> ## Title
>
> ```
> <p>Hello</p>
> ```

Is there a way to achieve this ? Or is it impossible with v-html ?

**EDIT :**

I create the content from a form (wysiwyg). Before saving the content, it's encoded with he.js, so it looks like :

```
&lt;h1&gt;Title&lt;/h1&gt;
&lt;pre&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Hello&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/pre&gt;
```

After getting it with my ajax function, I encode it with he.js to get :

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<pre>
    <p>Hello</p>
</pre>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060452/put-a-bit-of-html-inside-a-pre-tag

Comment: @RoyJ Perfect ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Try with this content:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<pre>
    &lt;p>Hello&lt;/p>
</pre>
```

So, you either have to escape the tags or separate the content of the **pre** tag from the rest of the HTML content.

I would personally do something like:

```
<div>
<h1>{{content.title}}</h1>
<pre>
    {{content.code}}
</pre>
</div>
```

And in your `data` you would have the `content` object:

```
content: {
 title: 'Title',
 code: '<p>Hello</p>'
}
```

But I do not know your exact use case and whether the HTML structure of your content can change or not.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, I edited my question so you have some more informations, if it can help :)

Comment: Well, in this case your question has nothing to do with vue.js but your question is how to decode all HTML tags except the content between the <pre> tags.

Comment: Oh I see... Was looking the wrong direction :/ Thank you, I'll try this way.